# How the looping with for in Python really works?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

I'm learning python and in a test, I made a class that have a list of numbers, in other class, a list of previous class. In the second class, I wrote a method for put the numbers dinamically but it put the numbers x times for the length of the list of previous class.

```
def make_connection(self, number):
        if not self.__has_con:
            for i in range(number):
                 self.__weight.append(1)
            self.__has_con = True
```

The method above is from the first class, to get n numbers.

```
inp = len(self.__inputs)

for n in self.__hidden:
    n.make_connection(inp)
```

This is from the second class. If __hidden has 9 objects, it put the inp 9 times for all the 9 elements.

init of second class

```
def __init__(self, array):
        if isinstance(array, list):
            if len(array) > 2:
                inps = []
                hidd = []
                outs = []

                for i in range(array[0]):
                    k = kn(kn.INPUT)
                    inps.append(k)
                for i in range(array[len(array)-1]):
                    k = kn(kn.OUTPUT)
                    outs.append(k)

                a = array[1:]
                h = a[:len(a)-1]

                if len(h) > 1:
                    for i in h:
                        hd = []
                        for p in range(i):
                            k = kn(kn.HIDDEN)
                            hd.append(k)
                        hidd.append(hd)
                else:
                    for p in range(h[0]):
                        k = kn(kn.HIDDEN)
                        hidd.append(k)

                self.__inputs = inps
                self.__hidden = hidd
                self.__output = outs
            else:
                inps = []
                outs = []

                for i in range(array[0]):
                    k = kn(kn.INPUT)
                    inps.append(k)
                for i in range(array[0]):
                    k = kn(kn.OUTPUT)
                    outs.append(k)

                self.__inputs = inps
                self.__output = outs
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Does it not work?

Comment: @figbeam it works, but not perfectly.
If inp is 2, all the n elements in hidden must have 2 '1' in the array, it occurs x times from the length of hidden.
So, if hidden has 3 elements, all these must have 2 'ones', but they have 6.

Answer (score 1):

The `for var in collection` syntax in Python uses an iterator. Instead of a for loop where you specify a starting value, an increment and a terminating value, it says iterate over all the values in the collection.

So when you say this in Python:

```
for x in range(4):
   print x
```

it's like saying this in other languages:

```
for (x = 0; x < 4; ++x) {
   print(x);
}
```

Python's `range` returns a iterator over 0..4 in this case. In your example, Python gives you each element of your collection.

See, for more details: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but if inp is 2, all the n elements in hidden must have 2 '1' in the array, it occurs x times from the length of hidden. So, if hidden has 3 elements, all these must have 2 'ones', but they have 6.
It runs the code for all variables in loop x times.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. You might have to show some more of your code for us to get the problem. As shown, each element in `self.__hidden` should have `inp = len(self.__inputs)` copies of `1`. Is it possible, by any chance, that your different instances of `n` share the same `self.__weight` list? That can easily happen in Python where lists or objects get copied as references instead of true copies. I would check your initialization code for a potential problem.

Comment: def __init__(self, type):
        self.__type = type
        self.__weight = []

This is how I create the n, the weight is set by make_connection method

Comment: https://pastebin.com/j4mbHEu3 This is how the n is implemented in the other class.

Comment: My corporate firewall blocks pastebin.com, can you maybe add that code as block quotes in the question instead?

Comment: Of course. It's done.

Comment: Looking at your code, my suspicion is that `k = kn(kn.HIDDEN)` somehow returns the same list each time, but reference, instead of creating a new copy. Here's a test to confirm this: after your `for n` loop, add `self.__hidden[0][1] = 42` and then `print(self.__hidden[1])`. If you see the change in `[1]` that you did in `[0]`, your bug is with `kn()` returning a reference to the same list each time.

Comment: the self.__hidden is a list of N's, it's saying that the object does not support item assignment. kn is the import for N class

Comment: Sorry, I got confused with your code. It's the different `__weight` instances that might be references to the same list, so you're looking for how that variable gets initialized, and the test would be something like `self.__hidden[0].__weight[1] = 42` followed by `print(self.__hidden[1].__weight)`.

Comment: When I print the __hidden after the for loop, I got it:

[<KAI.AI.KNeuron.KNeuron object at 0x0000017E0C810898>, <KAI.AI.KNeuron.KNeuron object at 0x0000017E0C8107B8>, <KAI.AI.KNeuron.KNeuron object at 0x0000017E0C810860>]

Comment: Did you also try `print(self.__hidden[0].__weight)` to see if it was different from the `[1]` output? Dig and look deeper, there's something odd going on, but I'm not sure I can help you much more.

Comment: My computer needed restart and now it's working. I didn't understand, but very thank you for help.

Answer (score -2):

In python Use the for loop like that:

```
for str in str_list
    print (str)
```

Comment: I used it, the code is in question.
It add to all elements multiple times.

inp = len(self.__inputs)

for n in self.__hidden:
    n.make_connection(inp)

 if inp is 2, all the n elements in hidden must have 2 '1' in the array, it occurs x times from the length of hidden. So, if hidden has 3 elements, all these must have 2 'ones', but they have 6. It runs the code for all variables in loop x times.

Comment: Sorry i can't understand your problem clearly, may be you need to intialize your variable that you are using in loop and then outside the loop print it may be it works.